# Python: Email users at 5am according to their timezone

Tags: python, pytz

Think Google calendar but I have a table with a list of reminders to send my users. Since my users are global, I can't email everyone at 5AM EST. I'll have a cronjob that runs every hour. If a record matches the date they've entered and 5AM, then email the user. I haven't figured out the SQL part of it yet, that should be easy (I think), for now I'm using static variables to test the functionality.

I guess my issue is, I want to make sure the script completes in less than a minute or else "5:01" comes around and people will miss their emails. There has to be a better way of doing this.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

d_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"

# This is the value pulled from the database. Format: (Y-m-d 05:00)
record_date = "2013-07-01 05:00"

# Current time in UTC
servertime = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))

# Let's assume the user lives on the West Coast
user1 = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))

if user1.strftime(d_format) == record_date:
    print "Send user an email!"
print ""

# Let's assume the user lives in Singapore
user2 = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Singapore'))

if user2.strftime(d_format) == record_date:
    print "Send user an email!"
print ""
```

Comment: Advice: make this much more robust.  Ensure that as long as it is any time after 5:00am in their timezone they will get mailed.  Also ensure that no matter how many times the script is run, each user only gets mailed once on a given date.  If something goes wrong, you may end up needing to re-run the script but without sending duplicates.

Comment: Time zones aren't all an integer number of hours off from UTC anyway; some are at 30 minutes or even 45 minutes off. Following @DrC's advice about robustness will avoid that problem (though they'll get their emails at 5:30 or whenever instead of 5).

Comment: Compare datetimes rather than strings. That way you can compare `hour` and leave `minute` alone.

Comment: Yep understood. I guess I should've wrote that I'm not all that well-versed with Python. I'm a PHP guy but I prefer to have Python handle the cronjob part of it.

Comment: @RedBaron - damnit, why didnt I think of that! Any drawbacks to that?

Comment: @luckytaxi None that I can think of. But DrC has some very sound advice

Comment: @Dougal I plan to ... The email doesn't need to reach them at exactly 5AM, anytime AFTER 5AM works for me. I actually plan on pushing the record into a queue and have it email accordingly.